# How to inspect an element's associated event handlers?

Tags: javascript, firebug

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to debug Javascript/jQuery event bindings with FireBug (or similar tool)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570960/how-to-debug-javascript-jquery-event-bindings-with-firebug-or-similar-tool)
>   [How to find event listeners on a DOM node when debugging or from the JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892)
>   [How to trace JavaScript events like onclick onblur?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91367/how-to-trace-javascript-events-like-onclick-onblur)

I am using Firebug to inspect HTML codes and CSS. I need to find what are the events and the handlers associated to an element.

Using the Inspect button, I can see all the CSS, but can't find the event handlers.

Comment: Check out the two related questions posted. They are what you are looking for.

Comment: I've already checked those before posting. They are not really duplicates. I'm looking for step-by-step ways to do it in Firebug, or maybe Firebug has no such feature?

Comment: Firebug doesn't have a feature like that. You have to use one of the methods that have been suggested.